# Does ANDROID_ID depend on the internet access?

Tags: android

ANDROID_ID is often suggested as a unique identifier for Android devices.   It's described as a "*A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.*"   (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html )

But I've seen some accounts on the web that the generation of the ANDROID_ID may be somehow related to or dependent on access to Google account information.  For example here [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Rn15F7Ku4GM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/Rn15F7Ku4GM/99hTPtQ1GkkJ)  and here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/y8nUytSKf7c/9kKLPjDrrEIJ.

The Android devices we ship with our products are unboxed and get their software installed in a secure environment without internet access - wifi yes, but no internet-  and many of our customers are also high-security sites which also block outside access.  Our Android devices are not associated with any sort of Google account.  Does ANDROID_ID have any dependencies on internet access, Google accounts or Google Play?

Comment: Given that you didn't like using the MAC address since you suspect you have seen it change, why are you interested in an identifier which is *clearly documented* to be subject to change?  More fundamentally, **Android is just not designed with the idea that licenses will be locked to a specific instance of hardware - rather, the assumption is that a license moves with a user (account) to their next device**.  Historically, trying to make Android do something contrary to its design intent has tended to be a battle that is ultimately lost, since it is a moving target.

Comment: I was worried about the MAC Address changing unpredictably since this has been reported on the web.    ANDROID_ID only changes under known, predictable circumstances that do not apply to our situation.  Really, Chris, chill out.

Answer (score 0):

The AOSP source code states in a comment:

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device. (The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.)

This explicitly refers to first boot, not to first internet interaction etc. (The text you plucked from the docs is less clear, stating "when the user first sets up the device").

Comment: You are reading a lot into this.  Also, there have been numerous examples of devices that don't implement this ID in precisely the way the spec suggests they should.